# How to test Promises in Jest

Tags: axios, jestjs

I'm facing some problems when testing my code with Jest. I tried a lot of solutions but I can't understand how to solve it.

Basically, I have two functions (getPromise1 and getPromise2) that create a axios instance and make a get request to an endpoint. Also, the getPromise1 function uses getToken function, that make another get request.

```
function get() {
  async function getToken() {
    const http = axios.create();

    return http
      .post("/endpoint-1")
      .then(response => response.data)
      .catch(error => { throw error });
  }

  const getPromise1 = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const token = await getToken();

    const http = axios.create({
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Token ${token}`
      },
    });

    return http
      .get("/endpoint-2")
      .then(response => resolve(response.data))
      .catch(error => reject(error));
  });
  
  const getPromise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const http = axios.create({
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Token 1234`
      },
    });

    return http
      .get("/endpoint-3",)
      .then(response => resolve(response.data))
      .catch(error => reject(error));
  });

  async function init() {
    const promises = Promise.any([getPromise1, getPromise2]);

    promises.then((u) => {
      return u;
    }).catch(error => {
      return error
    });
  }

  return init();
}
```

In my test, I used mockImplementation to mock post and get from axios, but in the expect block the number of calls are differents. I have 1 post and 2 get request, but when I tried to assert this I receive 1 post and 1 get, totalizing 2 requests.

```
axios.post.mockImplementation(url => {
  return Promise.resolve({
    status: 200,
    data: { data: '123' }
  })
})

axios.get.mockImplementation(() =>
  Promise.resolve({
    status: 200,
    data: {
      id: '123'
    },
  })
)

await get()

expect(axios.create).toBeCalledTimes(3)
expect(axios.post).toBeCalledTimes(1)
expect(axios.get).toBeCalledTimes(2)
```

Somebody can help me with this test?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is from using `Promise.any` like shown below:

```
const promises = Promise.any([getPromise1, getPromise2]);
```

> The Promise.any() static method takes an iterable of promises as input and returns a single Promise. This returned promise fulfills when any of the input's promises fulfills, with this first fulfillment value
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any

That means, there is no guarantee that both promises will even be executed (if the first promise is resolved before the second promise is even created or callback in second promise isn't executed yet, which in case it shall be since you are mocking, the second `get` call wont even executed).

What you instead want is `Promise.all`.

> The Promise.all() static method takes an iterable of promises as input and returns a single Promise. This returned promise fulfills when all of the input's promises fulfill (including when an empty iterable is passed), with an array of the fulfillment values
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all